# Issue regarding foreign key constraint

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 3 entities Role, Users and UserAssignedRoles. I have OneToMany bidirectional relation between Users and UserAssignedRoles and Roles and UserAssigned Roles respectively.
On firing the spring boot app, It throws an error

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`examserver`.`user_assigned_roles`, CONSTRAINT `FKkh4a308jmt2dwrbmohjlsxbrd` FOREIGN KEY (`role_fk`) REFERENCES `roles` (`role_id`))>

can anyone help me pointing where I did wrong.
the code of entities are here as follows.
Users.java

```
package com.examserver.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Table(name = "USERS")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Users implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String fname;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lname;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "Is_Profile_Active")

    private boolean active = true;

    @Column(name = "Contact_Number")
    private String phoneNo;
    @Column(name = "User_Description")
    private String about;
    @Column(name = "Profile_Image")
    private String dp;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<UserAssignedRoles> usersList = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<UserAssignedRoles> getUsersList() {
        return usersList;
    }

    public void setUsersList(Set<UserAssignedRoles> usersList) {
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    public Users() {
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<Authority> set = new HashSet<>();
        this.usersList.forEach(userAssignedRoles ->
                set.add(new Authority(userAssignedRoles.getRole().getRoleName())));

        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

and Role.java

```
package com.examserver.entities;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Table(name = "ROLES")
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Role_Id")
    private int roleId;

    @Column(name = "Role_Name")
    private String roleName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserAssignedRoles> userAssignedRolesSet;

    public Set<UserAssignedRoles> getUserAssignedRolesSet() {
        return userAssignedRolesSet;
    }

    public void setUserAssignedRolesSet(Set<UserAssignedRoles> userAssignedRolesSet) {
        this.userAssignedRolesSet = userAssignedRolesSet;
    }

    public Role(){

    }

    public Role(int roleId, String roleName, Set<UserAssignedRoles> userAssignedRolesSet) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.userAssignedRolesSet = userAssignedRolesSet;
    }
}
```

and UserAssignedRoles.java

```
package com.examserver.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Table(name = "USER_ASSIGNED_ROLES")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserAssignedRoles {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userRoleId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name ="Role_FK")
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "User_FK")
    private Users user;


}
```

PS: I am using the Spring Security so the I implemented the Userdetails interface to User entity.

Comment: My guess would be that you have a Liquibase/Flyway changelog which Spring Boot is trying to execute. Some entries in that changelog are conflicting causing your error at startup. But without further context it's hard to say. Could you check if there is a property "spring.liquibase.change-log" or something related to Flyway in your application.properties/.yml file?

Comment: Jonck van der Kogel what type of context yousre talking about.

Comment: As in, the rest of your code and config. Which is why I asked if you see a Liquibase or Flyway changelog in your resources.